# Artifactory and ECDSA Signing Keys

Tags: artifactory, digital-signature, ecdsa

I am trying to upload an ECDSA signing key to Artifactory Cloud, and am having zero success in finding any documentation that would help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Anyone have clues or breadcrumbs or a working framework?

I've tried using openssl and ssh-keygen to create the keys, and exported them into many formats. After first having failures with passphrase-protected keys, I tested various iterations, none with success. e.g.,

```
 openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out ecdsa.private
 openssl ec -in ecdsa.private  -pubout -out ecdsa.public
```

From the UI, calls to the API `api/v1/ui/security/keyPairs/verify` consistently fail. I pulled the OSS code in hopes of some insight, but since that doesn't include keysigning capabilities, I didn't have luck. Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 0):

Well -- I figured this out. Artifactory expects PEM-encoded RSA signing keys that were created with openssl. But after some digging I found that the ECDSA keys are verified through the same functions that verify GPG keys:

"public class org.artifactory.addon.common.keys.EcdsaKeyPairVerifier extends org.artifactory.addon.common.keys.GpgKeyPairVerifier"

This whole journey pertained to npm repositories and the switch to ECDSA signatures https://docs.npmjs.com/verifying-registry-signatures Artifactory doesn't seem to support the `registry-host.tld/-/npm/v1/keys` endpoint so I'm not certain this is a functional feature, anyway.